# Where is the jug of oil that never ran dry?

Tags: history, miracles, 1-kings

Following this [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31556/elijah-the-barrel-of-meal-shall-not-waste-neither-shall-the-cruse-of-oil-fail) I'd like to ask if there are any records where the jar was left.

> [1 Kings 17:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Kings+17%3A16&version=NIV) (NIV)
>   For the jar of flour was not used up and the jug of oil did not run
>   dry, in keeping with the word of the LORD spoken by Elijah.

It must be very precious to posses a jar like that so I would assume that it would be passed down from generation to generation. Does the Catholic Church or any other Christian or Jewish tradition record where the jar was left and if we still are able to witness?

Did any historians or archaeologist try to find or mention its present among us. I saw a documentary on lost Ark of the Covenant so I got the idea that other miracles of God that happened before should be still around us.

Who would get rid of the jar like that unless it wasn't a miracle at all but metaphoric.

Comment: I can think of a thousand reasons why a jug would not be found, blessed or otherwise - earthquake, dropped and broken...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to read the rest of the passage.  [Verse 14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+kings+17%3A14&version=ESV) reads:

> For thus says the Lord, the God of Israel, ‘The jar of flour shall not be spent, and the jug of oil shall not be empty, **until the day that the Lord sends rain upon the earth.**’”

Thus we can assume that once the rain came, and there was no longer a need for the flour and oil to be provided directly by God, that the jar and jug returned to being just like any other normal jar and jug.